# pip3 dateparser gives error with gcc

Tags: mac, pip, python3, macos-highsierra

I run Mac High Sierra and got python3 via brew. I wanted to pip3 dateparser, but got this error:

```
command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I followed a hint from https://github.com/maciejkula/glove-python/issues/55 (panaali commented on Nov 12, 2017) and did the following change:

```
brew install gcc
```

and then export gcc into CC like:

```
export CC=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.3.0/bin/g++-8
```

But then I got the new error

```
self->locale_info = re_alloc(sizeof(RE_LocaleInfo));
                                 ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    error: command '/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.3.0/bin/g++-8' failed with exit status 1
```

Afterwards I downloaded dateparser manually and wanted it to set up via:

```
git clone https://github.com/scrapinghub/dateparser.git
cd dateparser
python setup.py install
```

but this gives me the same error:

```
regex_3/_regex.c:26401:37: error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to
'RE_LocaleInfo*' [-fpermissive]
         self->locale_info = re_alloc(sizeof(RE_LocaleInfo));
                             ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ error: Setup script exited with error: command
'/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.3.0/bin/g++-8' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue doing `pip install dateparser`.

Fix: use `xcode-select --install` to install command line developer tools.